# How does dodge work?

Tags: league-of-legends

How does dodge work in League of Legends? Could it happen only if you are target of auto-attacking or also when enemy uses abilities like, for example, Ashe Volley?

Comment: A note should be added that dodge is now removed from the game.

Comment: This question references an out of date mechanic, hence the close.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot dodge abilities (whether auto or not) nor turret attacks. This [link](http://www.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=693655) provides more detail as to why this isn't possible.

The bottom post at the link sums it up nicely:

> You can't dodge abilities, even ones
>   that channel through a character's
>   autoattack.
>
> You can't dodge turrets, though I
>   think pre-nerf Jax used to be able to.
>
> Yes, you can dodge while casting and
>   being attacked from behind.

Comment: Care to summarize the details here @Anzeo?

Comment: @Ivo Flipse, I've updated my answer

Comment: This link is a good guide as to how dodge scales: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Dodge

Answer (score 4):

Straight from [League of Legends - Champion Stastics](http://www.leagueoflegends.com/learn/gameplay/champion-statistics)

> Dodge: Dodge gives your champion a
>   chance to completely avoid an enemy
>   physical attack. Attacks avoided in
>   this way will deal 0 damage and will
>   not apply 'on-hit' effects. However,
>   abilities which significantly modify
>   the champion's attack such as Twisted
>   Fate's Pick a Card, Nidalee's
>   Takedown, and others will always
>   strike, even when dodged. Dodge scales
>   multiplicatively, meaning that if you
>   have two sources of dodge each
>   providing 10%, you would have 19%
>   dodge (0.9 chance to be hit * 0.9
>   chance to be hit = 0.81 chance to be
>   hit)

However it should be noted that there has been report of a bug/glitch with Poppy's Devastating Blow that causes Poppy to "Miss" or the target to "Dodge" the attack when the ability is activated prior to the end of the previous attack animation. Also, the description right from Riot seems to indicate that the dodge text may still appear on attacks like Nasus's siphoning strike while the ability will hit anyway.

Comment: Fun stuff when you use a Blind on Xin Zhao; his third attack still knocks you up (even though it "missed").

Comment: @Raven Yeah, I was playing Teemo recently and thought I was safe after the blind and was running. Only to be knocked up and finished by Xin and his ally.

Comment: @Raven Yep, that feels totally broken to me. Does it do the same if you dodge said auto attack?

Comment: @Danixd - Blitz's powerfist works the same way nowadays. It's because the knockup effect isn't considered an on-hit effect, it's just part of the ability.